# jvisualvm can not locate Java installation

Tags: java, visualvm, jvisualvm

I am facing  following issues while running jvisualvm -

Java Related environment variables set on machine

[image: java related environment variables]

Following are `PATH` variable details, there is no path mentioned as `C:\apps\Java8`

```
Path=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\windows\system32;
C:\windows;
C:\windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;
D:\apps\gradle-5.5.1-bin\bin;
D:\apps\apache-ant-1.10.5\bin;
C:\apps\Java\Java8\bin;
C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
```

When I am running jvisualvm.exe, I am getting following error, from the error it seems that jvisualvm is looking into some config file to locate JDK home path:

[image]

On this message I click "Yes" button then getting following error which says, you are running VisualVM is running from JRE -

[image]

Comment: I have some question about your Java setup. Is there a full JRE installation in `c:\apps\java\java8\jre`? What is in `c:\apps\java8` directory? Is there or was there JDK installed?

Comment: C:\apps\java\java8  is JDK installation.  I don't have anything in "c:\apps\java8".

Comment: Ok, please start jvisualvm from WIndows command prompt with `jvisualvm.exe --trace <path_to_log_file>` and publish the content of the log file.

Comment: Try updating jdk path in visualvm.conf in "etc" folder.

Answer (score 33):

Try updating JDK path in `visualvm.conf` in the `etc` folder.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

As explain [here](https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/issues/112) and by Tarun Chopra.

You have 2 options:

1. Launch `bin/visualvm.exe` at the command line with the `--jdkhome` parameter and your JDK location
2. Update the `visualvm_jdkhome` variable in the file `etc/visualvm.conf` of your VisualVM directory.

Comment: NB: The JDK location must be the absolute path (exemples: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-17.jdk/Contents/Home, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Open C:...\visualvm_217\etc\visualvm.conf

uncomment line 72

#visualvm_jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"

and specify you jdk location

visualvm_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2"

good luck